# How to create a fluent style MVC 2 Html.Helper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Could someone point me in the right direction on how would I go about creating htmlhelpers that you could call in the view something like the code below.

```
   <% using (Html.BeginSvg())
   {%>
   <% using (Html.BeginGroup("Group1")) {%>
        <%= Html.SvgLine("Line1").Class("blueLine").Style("stroke-width:2px").X1(25).Y1(25).X2(25).Y2(25).Transform().Scale(-2)%>
        <%= Html.SvgLine("Line1").Class("blueLine").Style("stroke-width:2px").X1(100).Y1(25).X2(100).Y2(125).Transform().Scale(-2)%>
   <%} %>
   <%= Html.SvgRect("box").Class("redBox").X(12).Y(10).Width(234).Height(200) %>
<%} %>
```

Is it possible? is it sane? :) is there something like this already implemented?

Cheers
Si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's been done but Fluent Interfaces are awesome...here's a very basic implementation for you.

```
public static class SvgLineHelper {
    public static SvgLine SvgLine(this HtmlHelper helper, string name) {
        return new SvgLine(name);
    }
}

public class SvgLine {
    string _name;
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _width;
    int _height;
    IList<string> _styles;

    public SvgLine(string name) {
        _styles = new List<string>();
        _name = name;
    }

    public static SvgLine Create(string name) {
        return new SvgLine(name);
    }

    public SvgLine X(int x) {
        this._x = x;
        return this;
    }

    public SvgLine Width(int width) {
        this._width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public SvgLine Style(string style) {
        this._styles.Add(style);
        return this;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        //create your string from this object here
        return string.Format("x:{0}, width:{1}, style:{2}", _x, _width, _styles[0]);
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it in your html

```
<% Html.SvgLine("test").X(100).Width(50).Style("stroke-width:2px").ToString() %>
```

You have to call the tostring method as the last call (or another method that finalizes your fluent interface - the one that returns a string representation of your object)

Comment: Hi Morder, definatly pointed me in the right direction there, thanks.

Comment: Using this method would there be any way to build logic in, i.e. 

<% Html.SvgLine("test").X(100).X

If you have already set X it makes no sense to set it again.

Comment: Not really, since it's just a regular function call and not really subject to those types of rules...you can ignore any subsequent steps, however, by checking if the internal value is set first.

Answer (score 0):

Html helpers called with `<%=` must return `string` or `MvcHtmlString`. So the API you propose won't work unless you add a `ToString` or something at the end, like:

```
<%= Html.SvgLine("Line1").Class("blueLine").ToMvcHtmlString() %>
```

Alternately, you could pass a fluent config object as an argument to `SvgLine`:

```
<%= Html.SvgLine(With().Name("Line1").Class("blueLine")) %>
```

Either way would work. Pick whichever you like.

Comment: I don't think that you have to actually make/call ToString method. object.ToString() should be called automatically, all you have to do is override it.

Comment: @Necros: Not for `MvcHtmlString`, no. And I'm guessing that he's returning angle brackets, so that is what he needs for ASP.NET 4.

Comment: If you want to use `<%:`, then yes, you need `MvcHtmlString`. For `<%=`, string will do.

Comment: Well, right, but there is *no* good reason to not support `<%:`